# react-chartjs-2 Add additional labels

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-chartjs-2

[image]

I'm trying to achieve label shown in the picture (number 5). It shows total number on items for each graph. How do I achieve this with react-chartjs-2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed this simply using css relative and absolute positioning properties.